# Grails composite id throwing NullPointerException

Tags: grails, nullpointerexception, grails-orm, composite-key, grails-domain-class

I have a Grails 2.2.3 domain class that is throwing a NullPointerExeption regarding my composite id when I use dynamic scaffolding. I would just use the `pidm` field as the primary key, but *occasionally* there are two records with the same `pidm` (same employee, but maybe there is a name change or something) and Grails has trouble with the /show/ URI because multiple rows are returned. That is where the `changeIndicator` comes in - if changeIndicator is null, they are a current Employee. I'm wondering if the problem is that the pidm and changeIndicator are of two different types.

Does anyone know what the error might be?

Below is the class and error:

```
class Employee implements Serializable {

Integer pidm
String sid
String firstName
String lastName
String middleInitial
Character changeIndicator

static mapping = {
    table 'employee'

    id composite: ['pidm', 'changeIndicator']
    columns {
        pidm column: 'PIDM'
        changeIndicator column: 'CHANGE_IND'
        // more mappings
    }
    version false
}
```

Error:

```
URI
/phoneauth/employee/list
Class
java.lang.NullPointerException
Message
Cannot get property 'id' on null object
```

Comment: So you have the table named as `table`?  [`table 'table'`]

Comment: No, I just thought it would be more secure if I didn't put in the db table name. Just ignore that.

Edit: I changed it so it makes a bit more sense now.

Comment: How are you trying to access this domain class? Controller code is necessary to debug where you are accessing `Employee`.

Comment: I was trying to access the class via `static scaffold = true`. The problem is probably the Hibernate not allowing nullable columns in composite primary keys thing, as there are definitely some null values in the CHANGE_IND column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary issue is that Hibernate does not allow a nullable column as part of a composite primary key.

Secondarily, the Grails scaffold plugin does not handle composite keys very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate-views and put explicit all model's propetries in indesx.gsp (Example):

<f:table collection="${domainTestList}" properties="['pro1', 'pro2', 'pro3', 'pro4']" />

I hope that makes sense!